# How do I stop recruiters bothering me with clearly unsuitable positions?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I get quite a few messages from recruiters through stack overflow. It often starts with them saying how great my profile looks and how they think I'd be a great fit for a position they have. The problem is that the position on offer is totally unsuitable and its clear they haven't read my profile at all; its likely an automated message.

My developer story explicitly calls this out;

> I'm open to offers for lead developer or architect roles in the Thames
>   Valley. I might consider relocation and can be a successful
>   home/remote worker.
>
> **I won't consider anything that requires me to live in/commute to
>   London.**

but most of the positions I get contacted about are for mid/senior developers or for jobs that are based in London. Here is the most recent example;

> **Senior Java developer- Central London**
>
> Tom Shannon, Knowit
>
> Qwerky,
>
> Awesome profile!
>
> I'm currently working with a seriously cool late stage start-up travel
>   site Called Loveholidays.com, have you heard of them before?
>
> They're looking for a Senior Java developer to join them in their
>   office based in Hammersmith. The tech stack includes Java 8 and
>   Spring. You look like you'd be an amazing fit.
>
> Are you interested?
>
> Tom

I would love the developer story to have some preferences that would exclude me from searches, like excluding me from jobs in a location.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if you simply ask Tom if he did notice the restrictions you stated and still insisted on calling your profile awesome and contacting you, knowing you would refuse. If they respond: *yeah, tried it anyway* you can put Knowit on your mental blacklist. Alternatively respond to them with a link to this meta-post so recruiters learn that we really don't like that our concerns are set aside only for the benefit of the recruiter to meet their targets.

Comment: Not sure a filter would help much. I imagine the recruiter would search for something like [Java] in UK and skim a few profiles. They may even just think their job is so awesome that you still might consider it. Your only solutions may be to reply with a stern message of annoyance (probably not a good idea!) or flag the post.

Comment: Yes, but, what if *this role* is *so **amazing*** that you'd *reconsider your position on commuting*?! Have I told you yet how *amazing* this role is?

Comment: (and for the record: I do commute to London, but only because my current position is *actually* so amazing that I did reconsider, so hey, the possibility technically exists)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I did it for a while and hated it so much - never again

Comment: @Qwerky: I'm right now sitting on the train back up to Cambridgshire. I have a seat. I have power, and I have WiFi. I brought a nice snack from the office, and a drink, so I am comfortable enough. I have headphones too, but I don't use them right now. I work with amazing people at an amazing company, I get to travel to amazing places from time to time, and I've never felt so supported by an employer in my life. They did really earn their #1 spot on the Glassdoor top companies list this year, and that has raised my tolerance for the commute considerably.

Comment: @Qwerky: of course, that also makes them an exception to the rule; the majority of companies do not offer such an amazing position, one that makes the commute into London worth it.

Comment: If we find a way to fix this, please let's share it with LinkedIn.

Comment: Who is this “Tom” anyway? The job is not in his gift. He seems to have no connexion with the company at all. He’s just a would be self styled agent. That’s a thing to do? What’s to stop me spending my time looking for job listings and CVs and pretending to hook them up and asking for a finders fee? This is appalling. It’s bad enough when I get emails from people who claim to be from Facebook or Google; now we get emails from any old Tom Dick or Harry?